# BizTalk 2013 R2- orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

What is different between dehydrated and rehydrated activities for BizTalk messages process?

And when I can get dehydrated messages to suspended and resume instance?

Any one can get explained with examples that will be appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A message & orchestration will dehydrate if they are generally either waiting for a response.  It will rehydrate once the response is received.

A message will suspend if it times out or receives a error condition.

Comment: Generally this is happening mostly with WCF-Custom SQL adapter during dead-lock or in other case end-point get down right ?

Comment: @DipenPatel It can happen with any adapter.

Comment: Thanks for explaining 